# Referring again to original selection in jQuery chain

Tags: jquery

I have a "clicker" div and a "popup" div. The clicker div has an 'originalcolor' attribute that describes the color the clicker was originally. When the popup is double-clicked I want to hide the popup and change the color of the clicker back to the color defined in its originalcolor attribute.  The code below works but it seems like there should be a cleaner way to get the #clicker selection the second time in line 3, than repeating `$('#clicker')`.

```
$('#popup').dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#clicker').css('background-color', $('#clicker').attr('originalcolor'));
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: There isn't, other than storing it in a variable beforehand. Ah, so there is another way. But storing it in a variable would be cleaner imo.

Comment: Is the `originalcolor` attribute dynamic? If not, you could just use `.css('background-color', 'color')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `.css` a function instead of the value:

```
$('#clicker').css('background-color', function(){
    return $(this).attr('originalcolor');
});
```

Or, more simply, cache `$('#clicker')`:

```
var $c = $('#clicker');
$c.css('background-color', $c.attr('originalcolor'));
```

Comment: These suggestions all repeat, in some way, the original selection.  I was thinking that being in the chain, there might be some clever way from there to reference the original selection, but I guess not.  Thanks.

Comment: @Steve: It's not in any sort of "chain".  You're calling a function and passing it a parameter.  It has no idea what "context" the function is in when you call it.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible cleaner way I see here is to cache the jQuery selection result:

```
$('#popup').dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    var $clicker = $('#clicker');
    $clicker.css('background-color', $clicker.attr('originalcolor'));
});
```